# Когда происходит определение константы Q_OS_WIN32?

Tags: c++, qt, препроцессор

Хочу использовать кроссплатформенную функцию sleep. В одном из вопросов было предложено [такое вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918206/cross-platform-sleep-function-for-c) решение. Поскольку в qt есть такие константы как [Q_OS_WIN32](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_OS_WIN32) и [Q_OS_LINUX](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_OS_LINUX), решил использовать их, нежели определять какие-то свои.
Проблема в том, что эти константы почему-то не видятся (оба блока серые), а если в .pro файле прописать `DEFINES += Q_OS_WIN32`, вываливается множество ошибок о переопределении дефайна, т.е. когда-то он все же определяется, просто происходит это позже обработки файла с функцией.
Пробовал инклюдить ее как можно ниже, но не помогает.
Пробовал инклюдить в самом верху мэйна QtGlobal, поскольку константы находятся там, но тоже не помогло.
Как правильно разрешить эту проблему?

Comment: «Пробовал инклюдить в самом верху мэйна QtGlobal» — это должно решить проблему, не может быть, что не решает.

Comment: @ixSci, ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ оба блока кода серые, во время компиляции вываливается варнинг о  неиспользуемой переменной sleepMs, что говорит о пустом теле функции. Не знаю, может нужно еще какие-то действия предпринять перед сборкой.

Comment: "Хочу использовать кроссплатформенную функцию sleep" чем не устраивает штатная Qt функция `QThread::msleep()`? Коль скоро вы используете Qt, используйте ее возможности по максимуму

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге, проблему решило подключение файла `<QtGlobal>` непосредственно в заголовочный файл с этой функцией (а не в самый верх main, как было описано в вопросе).
Понятия не имею, как это могло повлиять, возможно, в процессе оптимизации кода был изменен порядок дефайнов, но не рискну с уверенностью это утверждать.